# Python: counting specific words in file of corpus

Tags: python, nltk

I would like to count specific words in each file of my corpus..
here is my code.. it works fine.

```
num=   nltk.FreqDist(
      (target,fileid)
       for fileid in reader.fileids()
       for w in reader.words(fileid)
       for target in ['have'])
```

but results is like this..
FreqDist: '2009.txt': 141205, '20.txt': 43201, '2.txt':41232, '4.txt':40859, 
'5.txt': 40805,.....

I would like to see all values one by one in a row. like..

'2009.txt' 141205

'20.txt' 43201

I tried this code additionally

```
  for results in num:
      print results
```

But it shows only 'have',''200.txt'... no FreqDist number is shown.

Also, I tried also nltk.ConditionalFreqDist().. It takes FOREVER..

I don't know why..
Please help me. I spent almost 4-5 hours for taking care of this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with NLTK, but it seems you are traversing a dict-like object.

What about this?

```
for file, n in num.iteritems():
    print file, n
```